# Database Locking issue android

Tags: android, database, database-connection, android-sqlite

I am getting Databse locking issue. I have One class which extends Activity and create instance of database there only. 
This is my super class

```
public class Example extends Activity
{

    protected DBUtil mDbUtil;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbUtil = DBUtil.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        mDbUtil.close();
    }
}
```

This is my Database class

```
    public class DBUtil extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static  DBUtil getInstance(Context context) {
            if(mInstance == null && context != null) {
                mInstance = new DBUtil(context);
                mDatabase = mInstance.getWritableDatabase();

            }
            if(mDatabase!=null && !mDatabase.isOpen())
            {
                mDatabase=mInstance.getWritableDatabase();
            }
            return mInstance;
        }


public boolean replaceOrUpdate(DBListener dbListener,final String sTable, ContentValues[] contentValues) {
        this.mDbListener=dbListener;

        if(mDatabase == null) {
            mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        }
        mDatabase.beginTransaction();
        try {
            int count = contentValues.length;
            for (int i=0; i<count;i++) {
                ContentValues value = contentValues[i];
                long id = mDatabase.replaceOrThrow(sTable,null,value);
                debug("Insert id = " + id);
            }
            mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
            mDbListener.onCompleteInsertion();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Exception = " , " " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            mDatabase.endTransaction();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean replaceOrUpdate(final String sTable, ContentValues[] contentValues) {

        if(mDatabase == null) {
            mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        }
        mDatabase.beginTransaction();
        try {
            int count = contentValues.length;
            for (int i=0; i<count;i++) {
                ContentValues value = contentValues[i];
                long id = mDatabase.replaceOrThrow(sTable,null,value);
                debug("Insert id = " + id);
            }
            mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Exception = " , " " + e.toString());
        }finally {
            mDatabase.endTransaction();
        }
        return true;
    }

        public void close() {
            if(mDatabase != null) {
                miDbOpenCounter--;
                mDatabase.close();
            }
            mInstance = null;
            mDatabase = null;
        }

    }
```

My all Activity extends Example

I open Activity A(Without finishing)->Activity B(Without finishing it)->Activity C
Activity c returns result and closes itself by calling finish() after insertion in Db. But while insertion it gives me   `mDatabase.endTransaction();` error here as nullPointer exception then Database lock exception

```
04-01 18:19:24.624: I/SQLiteConnectionPool(25638): The connection pool for +data+data+com_example_Example+databases+Example_db has been closed but there are still 1 connections in use.  They will be closed as they are released back to the pool.


04-01 18:19:24.624: W/System.err(25638): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at com.example.examp.DBUtil.replaceOrUpdate(DBUtil.java:150)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at com.example.examp.SignupMerchant.onCompleted(SignupMerchant.java:342)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at com.example.examp.ExampleAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ExampleAsyncTask.java:284)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at com.example.examp.ExampleAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ExampleAsyncTask.java:1)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 18:19:24.639: W/System.err(25638):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
04-01 18:19:24.684: D/dalvikvm(25638): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1556K, 27% free 22981K/31248K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
04-01 18:19:24.684: W/System.err(25638):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-01 18:19:24.684: W/System.err(25638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 18:19:24.684: W/System.err(25638):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-01 18:19:24.684: W/System.err(25638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
04-01 18:19:24.684: W/System.err(25638):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
04-01 18:19:24.684: W/System.err(25638):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


04-01 18:19:27.524: E/SQLiteLog(25638): (5) database is locked
04-01 18:19:27.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(25638): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.examp/databases/Example.db'.
04-01 18:19:27.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(25638): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
04-01 18:19:27.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(25638):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-01 18:19:27.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(25638):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
04-01 18:19:27.544: E/SQLiteDatabase(25638):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:825)
```

any idea to get out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `close()` method nulls the `static` variables shared between all activities regardless of the database being still open in some other activity.

Consider redesigning your app so that you don't have `static` variables here. It's perfectly ok for each activity to create a database connection of its own.

Comment: If I close db connection only when my app is exiting.Will that solve a problem?

Comment: It probably prevents the crash but doesn't solve the inherent problem of static data and its shared ownership. For which the best solution is often getting rid of shared ownership by removing the staticness.

Comment: cool. I will do that. I will remove static implementation and will switch back to the one instance per activity.